# What are the accessibility (a11y) guidelines for command line applications?

Tags: command-line-interface, accessibility

Is there anything comparable to the accessibility initiatives such as [WAI - Web Accessibility Initiative](https://www.w3.org/WAI) in the world of command-line tools?

How can developers of an open-source command-line tool evaluate if they conform well to [VPAT - Voluntary Product Accessibility Template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voluntary_Product_Accessibility_Template) in the US or similar documents for European Union, etc?

Answer (score 3):

Not to my knowledge. But command line tools are generally much simpler than GUI tools. They express almost everything in text, and rely almost entirely on keyboard operation, so that's two major 'problems' solved right away. It therefore should be possible to make a command line tool compliant with some or other accessibility standard - as long as **the Terminal app itself** has some kind of communication with Assistive Tech, [which is not guaranteed](https://jfw.groups.io/g/main/topic/commandline_accessibility/3286610?p=,,,20,0,0,0::RecentPostDate%2FSticky,,,20,2,0,3286610).

Once you have found [a Terminal which plays well with a screen reader](https://nvda.groups.io/g/nvda/topic/how_to_read_command_prompt/830352?20,0,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,2,0,830352), inspect very closely how it announces any help/manual content. Make sure that the stream of text-to-speech is meaningful, and 'massage' the copy to clarify anything which might be muddled. Also pay attention to any echo output. Aim to echo only the most meaningful stuff (or offer a flag to suppress verbose output).

Watch out for any 'cute' tricks such as ASCII animations, or making value distinctions with color codes, and if these things don't get announced, complement them with something clearer, in plain text, or drop them altogether.

Check [what standard](https://www.logicsolutions.com/508-ada-wcag-accessibility-difference/) you are aiming for (e.g. WCAG 2.0 Level AA, ADA, Section 508), check the spec against your command line tool to see if it violates any success criteria. Many of them will be Not Applicable. Fix the violations if you can. Make a list of all the success criteria in the standard you are aiming for, noting which ones you conform with, which ones are not applicable, and which ones you 'violate' making any exceptions absolutely clear - and that's pretty much the 'guts' of a VPAT.

Keep in mind that a VPAT is not a legal requirement, it is simply a widely approved way for a **vendor** (that's you) to document accessibility compliance within the marketplace (your customers/users). Some buyers will insist on a formal VPAT, especially for procurement in the US federal government, but there are other ways of documenting accessibility support, which your customers might find acceptable.